# What is the angle x?

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles, angle

[image]

> We have to find the angle x

I have tried using these theorems, but failed.

**1**. The angle at the centre is twice the angle at the circumference.

**2**. The exterior angle of a triangle is equal to the sum of the two opposite interior angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

**Hint:**

$\triangle AOC$ is isosceles
with
\begin{align} 
\angle OCA
=
\angle AOC
&=
\tfrac12\,(180^\circ-20^\circ)
=80^\circ
.
\end{align}

Comment: I tried to prove $\triangle AOC$ is isosceles but failed.So please help me to prove this.

Comment: @Supriyo Banerjee: can you see that $\triangle ACD$ is isosceles?

Comment: yeah, $\angle CDA$ & $\angle ACD$ are both $70^o$. So $\triangle ACD$ is isosceles.

Comment: @Supriyo Banerjee: well, then $|AD|=|AC|=|AO|$.

Comment: Yeah,then AC =AD & also AD=AO hence AO=AC .Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Consider the drawing. Extend AO to make diameter AD. Extend AC to make chord AE. Clearly AE and AB are symmetric about AD and are equal. FG is drawn with angle $30^o$ with FB at F, so its intersect with AB make a point which is symmetric with C about AD.  $\angle CAO=\angle DAB=20^o$. So points C, O and P(intersection of FD and AB) are on one circle(are cyclic) so $AO=AC$, that is triangle AOC is isosceles and $X=\angle AC0=80^o$.

Comment: FD & AB straight line can't intersect each other but you consider P as intersection of AB and FD.Also you wrote FD is drawn with angle $30^o$ with FB at F but how do you know that angle DFB = $30^o$

Comment: Sorry it is a typo. I meant  FG. I edited my answer.

Comment: what about P point?

Comment: Of course, P is the intersection of lines FG and AB.